# How display post's value custom field for product item which is placed on post as a shortcode [products]

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

Can you help me which way to look

1. I have a post with custom field «comp_city».
2. In the post I place the shortcode [products].
3. Product has two custom fields - «comp_name» and «comp_type».
4. For displaying products custom fields for items in post, i using this code:

```
add_action("add_fields_prod_item", "woo_add_fields_prod_item", 5);
function woo_add_fields_prod_item()
{
    global $post, $product;

    // Products custom fields

    $demo_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, "comp_name", true); // Name company
    $demo_servtype = get_post_meta($post->ID, "comp_type", true); // Type services

    // Post custom field

    $demo_city = get_post_meta($post->ID, "comp_city", true); // City name

    // Dispaly products custom fields

    if ($demo_name) {
        echo '<div class="cart-meta-attr"><span class="param">Name:</span> <span class="value">' .
            $demo_name .
            "</span> ";
    }
    if ($demo_servtype) {
        echo '<div class="cart-meta-attr"><span class="param">Type:</span> <span class="value">' .
            $demo_servtype .
            "</span> ";
    }

    // Dispaly post custom field

    if ($demo_city) {
        echo '<div class="cart-meta-attr"><span class="param">City:</span> <span class="value">' .
            $demo_city .
            "</span> ";
    }
}
```

5. Then add hook for woo_shop_add_to_cart_after

`<?php do_action( 'add_fields_prod_item' ); ?>`

6. It works only for products custom fields BUT don't work for post custom field

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Q6G.jpg)

**How display post's custom field «comp_city» for each products items?**

Have a post with custom field «comp_city». The value is the name of the city. Example, Colorado.
The post contains a shortcode [products]. I want to display value of post's custom field (city name) in product items. Code that i using works only for products custom fields BUT don't work for post custom field.

Comment: U need get_queried_object_id() to access the post. $post and $product in your case are objects from the product items loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything worked out according to your advice.